# Error command make of GarfRoot on Mac Sierra

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, root-framework

I am trying to install GarfRoot on a mac with Sierra OS, but I am not so familiar with makefiles.
When I launch make command I receive this error:

```
visitor-20939727:GarfRoot mekise$ make
c++ -Wall -Wextra -Wno-long-long `root-config --cflags` -O3 -fno-common -c -I/Users/mekise/garfield/Include -I/Users/mekise/garfield/Heed garfroot.C
c++ -o garfroot garfroot.o `root-config --glibs` -lGeom -lgfortran -lm -L/Users/mekise/garfield/Library -lGarfield -all_load
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [garfroot] Error 1
```

And this is the makefile:

```
OBJDIR = $(GARFIELD_HOME)/Object
SRCDIR = $(GARFIELD_HOME)/Source
INCDIR = $(GARFIELD_HOME)/Include
HEEDDIR = $(GARFIELD_HOME)/Heed
LIBDIR = $(GARFIELD_HOME)/Library

# Compiler flags
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Wno-long-long \
  `root-config --cflags` \
  -O3 -fno-common -c \
  -I$(INCDIR) -I$(HEEDDIR)

# Debug flags
# CFLAGS += -g

LDFLAGS = `root-config --glibs` -lGeom -lgfortran -lm
LDFLAGS += -L$(LIBDIR) -lGarfield
LDFLAGS += -all_load
# LDFLAGS += -g

garfroot:   garfroot.C 
  $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) garfroot.C
  $(CXX) -o garfroot garfroot.o $(LDFLAGS)
  rm garfroot.o
```

I can not figure out what it is.

Thank you all,
Stefano

Comment: You are likely missing a library, namely `gfortran`.

Comment: I've installed gfortran yet.